# Complement result from function in rendered attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered, boolean

So in my rendered attribute I am calling a getter method that returns a boolean. However I want to set rendered to the opposite of what it returns because it is used to render one component or another. What is the correct syntax for doing this?

I am aware that I can do this:

```
rendered="{!IF(selectedNameIsContact == false, true, false)}"
```

But I was hoping for a cleaner syntax such as

```
rendered="NOT{!selectedNameIsContact}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use double '!!'.  It looks funky, but it accomplishes what you are looking for

```
rendered="{!!selectedNameIsContact}"
```

> **EDIT**

As pointed out by @sfdcfox, you could also use

```
rendered="{!not selectedNameIsContact}"
```

Also pointed out by @Ralph, you could also use

```
{!selectNameisContact == false}
```

Comment: Also, `rendered="{!not selectedNameIsContact}"`. I'd avoid using !! directly, because it might be construed as a typo later.

Comment: Good point @sfdcfox.  Added to reflect.

Comment: The not does look a lot better than the double exclamation. Thanks for the input

Comment: where is `{!not someBooleanFieldOrProperty}` documented? I would have done this as `{!NOT(someBooleanFieldOrProperty)}`

Comment: you've also got `{!selectNameisContact == false}` as an option